# Odd result out of dplyr with max function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this rather simple piece of code where the resulting output is something I cannot understand.

```
library(dplyr)

allPerm <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:100), 4)) %>%
  rename_all(~c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")) %>%
  mutate(total = Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4) %>%
  filter(total == 100)

allPerm %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  mutate(Aa = max(0, Q1+Q2-60),
         Ba = (Q1+Q2),
         Ca = max(Q3-40, 0),
         Da = max(40-Q3, 0), 
         Ea = Q3,
         Fa = Q4,
         Bonus = (2.5*Aa+1.1*Ba-1.5*Ca+2*Da+Ea-2*Fa)) 

allPerm %>%
  mutate(Aa = max(0, Q1+Q2-60),
         Ba = (Q1+Q2),
         Ca = max(Q3-40, 0),
         Da = max(40-Q3, 0), 
         Ea = Q3,
         Fa = Q4,
         Bonus = (2.5*Aa+1.1*Ba-1.5*Ca+2*Da+Ea-2*Fa)) %>%
  head(10)
```

I am expecting the last two dplyr statements to return identical output, but this is not happening as you can see.
Something really weird seems to go on with the max function over the *Ca* variable in the mutate statement: it goes to 60 when it really shouldn't.

```
> allPerm %>%
+   slice(1:10) %>%
+   mutate(Aa = max(0, Q1+Q2-60),
+          Ba = (Q1+Q2),
+          Ca = max(Q3-40, 0),
+          Da = max(40-Q3, 0), 
+          Ea = Q3,
+          Fa = Q4,
+          Bonus = (2.5*Aa+1.1*Ba-1.5*Ca+2*Da+Ea-2*Fa)) 
    Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 total Aa  Ba Ca Da Ea Fa Bonus
1  100  0  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
2   99  1  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
3   98  2  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
4   97  3  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
5   96  4  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
6   95  5  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
7   94  6  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
8   93  7  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
9   92  8  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
10  91  9  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
> 
> allPerm %>%
+   mutate(Aa = max(0, Q1+Q2-60),
+          Ba = (Q1+Q2),
+          Ca = max(Q3-40, 0),
+          Da = max(40-Q3, 0), 
+          Ea = Q3,
+          Fa = Q4,
+          Bonus = (2.5*Aa+1.1*Ba-1.5*Ca+2*Da+Ea-2*Fa)) %>%
+   head(10)
    Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 total Aa  Ba Ca Da Ea Fa Bonus
1  100  0  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
2   99  1  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
3   98  2  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
4   97  3  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
5   96  4  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
6   95  5  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
7   94  6  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
8   93  7  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
9   92  8  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
10  91  9  0  0   100 40 100 60 40  0  0   200
```

Clearly the correct output is the first one.

I also tried to do this using a function where the *Bonus* variable is calculated by calling that function instead of having all the different component within the dplyr mutate statement. The result is identical.

Any help figuring out what I am doing/understanding the wrong way would be great.

Thanks.

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.5                         
year           2021                        
month          03                          
day            31                          
svn rev        80133                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
nickname       Shake and Throw 

dplyr 1.0.5
```

Comment: I don't see how you would expect these to return the same output? In the first chain of statements, you take a slice of the data (first 10 rows) and then perform the subsequent statements. In the last chain of statements, you perform the mutations before taking the first 10 rows.

Comment: I am mutating (that, I understand, is record-wise - by row), not grouping/summarising. The 10 rows I am playing with should be identical no matter what happens with the remaining ones. At least that's my understanding of how mutate works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `pmax` and not `max`. `max` returns only one number whereas `pmax` returns the same length as input.

See this small example to see how it works :

```
x <- c(1, 4, 5, 9)
max(x, 5)
#[1] 9

pmax(x, 5)
#[1] 5 5 5 9
```

Using `pmax` on your data :

```
allPerm %>%
  mutate(Aa = pmax(0, Q1+Q2-60),
         Ba = (Q1+Q2),
         Ca = pmax(Q3-40, 0),
         Da = pmax(40-Q3, 0), 
         Ea = Q3,
         Fa = Q4,
         Bonus = (2.5*Aa+1.1*Ba-1.5*Ca+2*Da+Ea-2*Fa)) %>%
  head(10)

#    Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 total Aa  Ba Ca Da Ea Fa Bonus
#1  100  0  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#2   99  1  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#3   98  2  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#4   97  3  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#5   96  4  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#6   95  5  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#7   94  6  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#8   93  7  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#9   92  8  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
#10  91  9  0  0   100 40 100  0 40  0  0   290
```

Your first example works because the first 10 rows have the same value for `max` and `pmax`.

Comment: I always assumed that mutate goes "row-wise". I mean: if a row has Q3 = 0, max(Q3-40, 0) should be 0 no matter what other rows in the df might have.

Comment: Unless you specify `rowwise` or `group_by`, `mutate` passes all the values of the column together to the function.